# java-sqlite-jdbc-query-is-returning-stale-data-from-open connection

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc

I'm using a JDBC for SQLite, the scenario is like given below: I am creating active.db in my /tmp location(in auto-commit mode).after 50 MB size reaches I move that database to /var location by renaming it to 1.db...so on and creating new active.db in /tmp location again.i am keeping open connection to active.db(/tmp location) from Java, as I need fresh data in every 2 seconds,  so not keeping connection to be closed just reusing it.now a problem is when I move active.db to /var location open connection to java gives me still an old data, not the refreshed one.PRAGMA journal_mode is set to DELETE in SQLite db.

I have gone through below links:

[Sqlite + Java: table not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472991/sqlite-java-table-not-updating)

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjlsuvejLPWAhVIRo8KHRAiB3UQFggnMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsqlite.org%2Fisolation.html&usg=AFQjCNHgGmwOaZLL8F34cwtrrdkXieCn9Q

https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_read_uncommitted

https://sqlite.org/tempfiles.html

Comment: Whether the referring locations are hardcoded? i.e. if in code /tmp is hardcoded, it will look there. Moreover these dynamic values need to be in configuration or xml files and hence no restart is required for webservers. If it is hardcoded or initialized via java code, explicit restart is required after deploying war file

Comment: @priyaraj it's not harcoded it's in properties files only,the problem is with old data even file is moved to new location.

Comment: ok, whether code is in webserver?whether properties file location can be accessed outside?it is better to have in web.xml if it is the case of web application rather than properties file. You can get the value of web.xml in your contextlistener easily

Comment: @priyaraj  it will be better if we can discuss more on problem i am having

Comment: please share your code. so that helps to further look

Answer (score 1):

The documentation ([How To Corrupt An SQLite Database File](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_unlinking_or_renaming_a_database_file_while_in_use)) says that

> unlinking or renaming an open database file results in behavior that is undefined and probably undesirable.